# Mathematically speaking, why can we use Fourier Transform when studying wind?

Tags: wind, mathematics, turbulence

As far as I understand, wind is stochastic on small scale. Then wouldn't that mean, since the function is not Riemann integrable, Fourier Transform cannot be used? What is the reason that climate researchers can use Fourier Transform successfully, while, for example, stock market analysts fail to do so?

Please correct me. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Frame challenge, part 1: The Fourier transform does not require the underlying function to be Riemann integrable. Part 2: Fourier analysis and similar spectral analysis techniques are widely used in the financial industry including analyses of the stock market.

Comment: I'm voting to close as needing clarification.

Comment: @DavidHammen "similar spectral analysis techniques are widely used in the financial industry " that does not mean they are *correctly* used. See Black-Scholes model catastrophy mostly due to wrong assumptions on its validity (let's shorten it to BS model ... even if backed by Nobel prizes or something like that).